# Spring request session management

Tags: java, spring, session, httprequest

How spring or java knows request is coming from same user, as http requests are stateless.
i got to know requestcontextfilter manages, but how it knows request is from same user.

Comment: it doesn't know. That's why, for instances with JWT,  you need to append as a header a token to each of your http request

Comment: okay, you are saying same token is added for same user request and checked in the server side. Any doc or link regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: quick search on google, found this: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world

Comment: You can have a look here : https://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-session-management-servlet-httpsession-url-rewriting. There are different ways to handle a session. Spring provides a seperate way to handle session. https://spring.io/projects/spring-session If you don't change the default the Tomcat server will set you a cookie with a session id ( Press F12 in the Browser and you'll see it or look at the cookies in postman)